# Plotting linear graphs from dummy variables in Stata

Tags: graph, plot, binary, stata, fractions

I want to plot linear graph of the fraction of 1's and 0's I have in my main variable of interest by gender.

I know how to do that using bargraphs, either using count or mean but these commands do not seem to work in twoway graphs.

Can someone provide me with a quick guide?

Comment: Please show the `twoway` code that does not work to get detailed comments. In general, however, you will need to create a mean and then plot it. The fraction of 1s is just the mean of an indicator variable and the fractions of 0s is its complement.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Nick. This is the code that I used for a bargraph, which works: graph bar (mean) fertzer, over(sexhead2) by(wave). Here fertzer is a dummy of if households use fertilizer or not, sexhead2 is also a dummy of whether the household head is a male or female and wave is a year dummy for 2011 and 2012 waves of survey. Ideally, I would like the same graph in a line graph so I tried graph twoway (mean) fertzer, over(sexhead2) by(wave) but then the command says that it doesnt recognize the variable mean.

Comment: Quite so. The syntax diagram for `twoway` makes it quite clear that such syntax is not allowed. I will post an answer.

Comment: You should not embed "long" code snippets within comments. It is unnecessarily difficult to read. You can edit your original post and include it there. The same applies to other code found within comment section of answers. I believe you can post an answer (yes,  to your own question) if you'd like to share your solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OP reports in a comment that this works:

```
graph bar (mean) fertzer, over(sexhead2) by(wave)
```

Here `fertzer` is an indicator variable (dummy, so-called) with value 1  if households use fertilizer and 0 otherwise; `sexhead2` is also an indicator for household head being male or female and `wave` indicates year 2011 or  2012.

But trying to get a line graph with this syntax fails:

```
graph twoway (mean) fertzer, over(sexhead2) by(wave)
```

Here is an analogue of this question with syntax that works:

```
sysuse auto, clear 

gen himpg = mpg > 20 

egen mean = mean(himpg), by(foreign rep78) 

line mean rep78, by(foreign) ytitle(fraction with more than 20 miles/gallon) yla(, ang(h)) sort 

twoway connected mean rep78, by(foreign) ytitle(fraction with more than 20 miles/gallon) yla(, ang(h)) sort
```

With `twoway`, unlike `graph hbar`, `graph bar` or `graph dot` you must create the means as a new variable before graphing. Syntax such as `(mean)` is not offered with `twoway`.

Comment: Since we are using "by" we have side by side graphs for 2011 and 12. However, I would like to graph fractions of males and females using fertilizer in the same graph and label my x-axis as the years(waves) instead such that males and females have different lines in the same graph. This is what I used: egen mean=mean(fertzer), by(wave sexhead2)
 line mean sexhead2, by(wave) ytitle(fraction of households using fertilizer) sort
 twoway connected mean sexhead2, by(wave) ytitle(fraction of households using fertilizer) sort, which gives me

Comment: Nick, I think I found what I was looking for. Here is what I have:                tw (connected mean wave if sexhead2 ==1) ///
 (connected mean wave if sexhead2 ==0), ytitle(fraction of households using fertilizer)